# How to write a bash script to submit jobs iteratively?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, hpc

I have some directories named say 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. How can I write a bash script to run the command "qsub job.sh" in each of these directories? Right now I individually go to each directory and run the command "qsub job.sh" in the terminal. All the directories already have the script job.sh.

Comment: Try `for dir in 1 2 3 4; do ( cd 1; qsub job.sh; ); done`. `( list )` executes the `list` in a subshell. If you want to run all jobs in parallel you can launch your `qsub` command in the background: `( cd 1; qsub job.sh & )`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet you could make this a proper answer.

Comment: @yugr I would, if I wasn't so sure that this is a duplicate.